# Want to pass multiple models to a view ASP .NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP .NET MVC4 structure. I want show messages list with different category like inbox, outbox and trash etc. message on my view. How can I pass multiple modal data to a single view that will show data with respective category. For example I want to show trash message inbox messages and sent messages in view then how can I pass all data with respective category to the view.

Here I have messages class that i want to use to pass data to view.

```
public class Messages
{
    public int message_Id { get; set; }
    public string message_subject { get; set; }
    public string message_description { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime message_date { get; set; }
    public int sender { get; set; }
    public int project_id { get; set; }
    public string message_size { get; set; }
    public string file_id { get; set; }
    public int reciever { get; set; }
    public int star { get; set; }
    public int read { get; set; }
    public string sender_name { get; set; }
    public string reciever_name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int isActive { get; set; }
}
```

Please if there any mistake to explain my problem please edit it. I have not good command in English. Thanks

Comment: 1. add a property into message class which is MessageStatus to represent Inbox, outbox etc. 2. use ViewModel which is an extra abstract sit on top of your core model for presentation purpose. when user posts data to the server, the data will be bind to the view model by the model binder. Then in the action you can map the view model to core model and manipulate them.

Answer (score 1):

create a view model

```
public class ViewModel{
    public List<Messages> Inbox { get; set; }
    public...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would start my renaming `Messages` to `Message` as it conceptually represents one message, not a collection.

Second, creating one single view for the whole thing may not be wise because it would imply to me that you are going to go to your data store and query all these messages at the same time.

Instead I would with a jQuery tab (or something similar) that would go and query an Json MVC action query for messages, on a paged basis.

Can't give a concrete example because there are so many ways to implement this, but the basics are to query for the necessary data upon when needed with ajax, limiting it to a page with an MVC (or WebAPI) action.

But if you don't care about performance, and its something quick you want I would do as Matt Bodily suggested.